# Abort cmake configuration if any step of custom command fails

Tags: python, cmake, python-venv

I would like to have a custom target which would prepare test environment, generate some related python code, etc.
Here is a part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(test_env
        COMMAND bash -c 'python3 -m venv ${DEPL_TEST_EXEC}/virtenv '  #step 1
        COMMAND bash -c 'java -jar ${SWAGGER_PATH}/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.15.jar generate -i ${SIGYN_SPECS}/mySpecialAPI.yaml -l python -o ${DEPL_TEST_EXEC}/mySpecialAPI' #step 2
        COMMAND bash -c \'
            . ${DEPL_TEST_EXEC}/virtenv/bin/activate\; #step 3
            pip install ${DEPL_TEST_EXEC}/mySpecialAPI/ #step 4
        ')
```

If step 1 or step 2 fails then next steps are not executed. But I cannot have steps 3&4 under different COMMAND section because step 3 activates virtual environment and step 4 installs a package into this environment.

At the moment if step 3 fails than step 4 tries to be executed, which I don't like. Is there a way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Since `step 3` and `step 4` are not "steps" from the CMake point of view, the question is not about CMake way but about a **shell** way for execute `step 4` if `step 3` succeed. There are many questions on this topic. See e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22738) suggesting approach `command1 &&  command2`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that helps. Thank you.